# How to model a vase with a hole through it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to model this vase on the left in this picture,

[image]

However, I'm still a beginner in Blender, and the furthest I could go is as depicted in the screenshot below:

[image]
As you can see, the beginning was promising, but applying the subdivider made it horrible.

I started from a cube building up, and used Boolean difference to subtract the hole inside.

I'm not looking for a full solution, I just need guidelines like how should I start? a plane? a cube?

shall I start from low model and then apply a subdivider? or I should start as smooth as possible?

**EDIT:**

I took @Simon approach, I started with a cylinder, squashed it at the bottom, and unsquashed at the top, after the boolean with another perpendicular cylinder, things got ugly and I had to cut faces to make them Quads instead of NGON.
This is the best I could do:
[image]

**EDIT2:**

More progress, this time, to do the boolean, I extracted the edge from the original body, and extrude it to create the boolean operand, this is the result before Subdivider modifier. Do I have to clean the body manually? like moving vertices, merging them, cut some faces? or there is a faster way (considering I have to repeat the process on four sides (unless I have to use Mirror))?

[image]

**EDIT 3**

I fixed the model after the boolean, and the results are better, but still can't get it perfect:

[image]

Especially these areas:
[image]

**Edit 4:**

I started over again, to follow @Simon instructions, the results? Amazing.
Check it out:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). You're on the right track. Your mesh has some large [N-gons](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-modeling/training/modeling/tris-quads-n-gons/), but Subdivision works best with Quads. Once you repair the topology, it will work just fine.

Comment: That's great, I like the page you shared, it is helpful. Do you suggest that I break them down manually into quads? or there is an easier way?

Comment: You are trying to chew too much. Instead of trying to make a custom thing without knowledge howto, make something following a tutorial step by step. Once you get enough experience shapes like these will be no problem.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I like to chew outside my comfort zone :D, also if you noticed there is huge progress since I asked the question. I feel I'm a few hours from answering my own question, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignore the hole to begin with. The main shape appears to be a squashed cylinder, so create the main outline by scaling down one axis, then loop cutting/extruding and scaling to create the overall shape. For the neck the shape is circular so un-squash this section. For the large hole, boolean a cylinder then clean up the geometry afterwards.

[image]
[image]

Start with a 16 sided cylinder. I used a 100mm rad and 350mm height. Scale it down on one axis. Add loop cuts.

[image]

From bottom ring to top I scaled by about .7, .9, 1, .9, .6, .1, .1. Rounded the neck rings. Added supporting loops for the neck and base. Inset and extruded the neck downward. Delete end N-Gons then used Grid Fill to finish.

[image]

Add a 10 sided cylinder and shape accordingly. I am trying to end up with an easy way to create quads after the boolean so am looking to position the new cylinder vertices close to the vase vertices.

[image]

Snap and merge the resulting vertices together, creating quads. Tidy up the mesh. At this step I deleted half the model and mirrored the mesh to save time. Remember to flip normals on the mirror. Add supporting loops to the inner ring.

[image]

Subdivision result. This worked out better than my first attempt as there are now no triangles in the bottom corners of the hole.

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Did you just create the model that I've been trying to create for hours as a quick answer? You, sir, are amazing.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you just put a detailed answer with steps and values that resulted in me being able to do the perfect version? I wish I can give you a reward. All I can give you is an upvote. I'm also marking this as answer.
To see my latest version, check the end of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your mesh has some large [N-gons](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-modeling/training/modeling/tris-quads-n-gons/), but Subdivision works best with Quads.

You can either repair the topology, or start from scratch with quads.
Depends on you, both ways are fine.

*Two ways of making quad topology.*
[image]

Comment: From that shape how do you "inflate" the rest?

Comment: Hello :). I'd add thickness and then used proportional scaling to 'inflate' it. But Simon's answer is way more elegant.

Comment: @JachymMichal as much as I liked your tip (it was really helpful) I had to go with Simon's answer as it really helped me to master this model.
Thanks a lot, I wish I can give you more than one upvote.

Comment: @NourSabouny Happy to help, good luck with your project :).